# React - FC - How to stop execution in react environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, error-handling, axios

Currently I have a React + Redux app.
I want to stop execution whenever any API call has been failed. Im calling API using axios.
I'm trying to stop execution by throwing error in the axios interceptor.

```
    axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
          (response: AxiosResponse) => response,
           async (failedRequest: iFailedRequest) =>
                 apiErrorHandler(failedRequest)
    );
```

Here is my `apiErrorHanlder` method.

```
const apiErrorHandler(failedRequest) = () => {
   throw new Error("error") // I want my application execution to stop here without affecting the UI state
}
```

But the problem is that in the react/JS execution continues to proceed to the next line of code.

```
const MyComponent = ()  => {

const apiCall = async () => {
   await axios.get("/api_end_point") // Stop execution here if API call has been failed
   console.log("success API call") // This should only be printed in case of successful API call
}

useEffect(() => {
   apiCall();
}, [])

return <></>;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try/catch block for that:

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

```js
try {
  await axios.get("/api_end_point")
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

Comment: May be my approach is wrong but I want to stop execution in `apiErrorHandler()`.  Is there any way ? This way I don't have to put try/catch block on every API.

Comment: Usually you need to handle those error responses and this is also the default behavior. I don't see another way to do it other than wrapping it into a try/catch or throwing an error like you did before.

Comment: The other ways would also take more code like defining a fallback value in case the responses are failing and react on your ui appropriately. And this is the better way that I would propose. Which means having some kind of value that you return in your error handler.